# appcfg.py: error: Error parsing app\app.yaml: Unable to assign value 'php55' to attribute 'runtime'

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Usage: `appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]`

**appcfg.py**: error:

```
 Error parsing app\app.yaml: Unable to assign value 'php55' to
attribute 'runtime':
    Value 'php55' for runtime does not match expression '^(?:contrib-dart|dart|go|ph
    p|python|python27|java|java7|vm|custom)$'
    in "app\app.yaml", line 4, column 10.
```

Initially I got following; but after updating `php` to `php55` I get above error.

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
PHP 5.4 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy PHP 5.4 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for PHP 5.4 deployment by visiting
```

I'm using AppEngine version 1.9.18 and using command `appcfg.py udpate my_app`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved after updating the App Engine version to 1.9.20